# Simulating r.v.'s from a joint density by rejection sampling in R. Continued

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, indefinite-integrals, sampling, simulation

I wish to sample variables $v$ and $w$ from the joint density $$(v+w)e^{-\frac{(v+w)^{2}}{2x_{0}}-2\mu v-(\mu -\lambda )w},$$
where $x_0$, $\mu$ and $\lambda$ can be seen as positive constant. Since there is a sum $v+w$, thus I replace it with $r=v+w$, and get $$f(r,v)=re^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2x_{0}}-(\mu -\lambda)r-(\mu +\lambda)v},$$ then the problem is reduced to sample $r$ and $v$. I use rejection sampling in R to simulate $r$ firstly, then conditional on $r$, simulate $v$, given $0<=v<=r$.

The marginal density of $r$ is $$f(r) =re^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2x_{0}}-(\mu -\lambda )r}(1-e^{-(\mu +\lambda)r})\frac{1}{\mu +\lambda }$$

Question: the histogram of $w$ shows negative value accidentally!

I set $Gamma(scale = 0.55, shape = 3.5)$ as a suitable enveloping distribution, $\mu=0.5$, $\lambda=1$, $x_0=0.945$, $M=2$. Here is the code.

```
# the marginal density of r
mu = 0.5
lambda = 1
x_0 = 0.945

ff <- function(r) {
r*exp(-r^2/(2*x_0)-(mu-lambda)*r)*(1-exp(-(mu+lambda)*r))/(mu+lambda) }

###########################   rejection sampling r
r=seq(0,7,0.01)
rejsampling <- function(M) {
while(1) {

# Draw single value from between zero and one
u = runif(1, 0, 1)

# Draw candidate value for r from the enveloping distribution
r = rgamma(1, scale = 0.55, shape = 3.5)

# Accept or reject candidate value; if rejected try again
if(dgamma(r,scale = 0.55, shape = 3.5)*u*M <= ff(r))  {
  return(r)
   }
 }
}

M = 2
sampr = replicate(100000, rejsampling(M))

hist(sampr, freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0,0.8), main = "f(r) by rejection sampling",breaks=100,xlab="r")
lines(r, ff(r), col = 2)
text(1.5,0.65,labels=paste("f(r)",sep=""),col=2)
lines(r, dgamma(r,scale = 0.55, shape = 3.5))
text(4,0.25,labels="Gamma(scale=0.55,shape=3.5)")

# Sampling v given r
v = rep(0,N)
x = rep(0,N)

for(i in 1:N) {
   x[i] = rexp(mu+lambda)
   v[i] = x[i]/(1-exp(-(mu+lambda)*sampr[i]))
}

hist(v, freq=FALSE, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,1), main = "v by rejection sampling",breaks=1000,xlab="v")


##### sampling w
w = rep(0,N)
w = sampr - v
hist(w,100)
```

Under this algorithm, we have $0<=w<=r$, But, as the following image showing that $w$ has a number of negative values, which should not happen. Any help will be the most grateful. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: And I did integrate the joint density $f(r,v)$ w.r.t $v$ from 0 to $r$, then $w$ should always be positive. Just wondering how it comes like this. Any idea? Many thanks.

Comment: At the line `w = sampr - v`, where is `v` coming from?

Comment: @Did Many thanks for your reminding. Sorry for missing the part of sampling $v$, just added to the code.

Comment: The trouble is at the line `v[i] = x[i]/(1-exp(-(mu+lambda)*sampr[i]))`, since it does not ensure that `v[i] < sampr[i]`. Additionally, I fail to see how this line guarantees that `v[i]` has the correct conditional distribution.

Comment: @Did This line comes from $$f(v\mid r)=\frac{f(r,v)}{f(r)}=(\mu +\lambda )\frac{e^{-(\mu +\lambda )v}}{1-e^{-(\mu +\lambda )r}}$$, which could be seen as a r.v $exp(\mu+\lambda)$ given $r$, so I generate $x\sim exp(\mu+\lambda)$.

Comment: Let me repeat: first, this density is restricted to $v<r$ hence generating an independent random variable $x$ exponential with parameter $\mu+\lambda$ does not meet this restriction; second, if $x$ has density $g(x)=(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)x}$ and if $k(r)=1-e^{-(\mu+\lambda)r}$, then the density of $x/k(r)$ is not $g(x)/k(r)$.

Comment: @Did I see, generating from $exp(\mu+\lambda)$ then being divided by $k(r)$ cannot secure $v$ has that conditional distribution. So I use the inverse of cdf of $f(v\mid r)$, then sample $w$ from $sampr-v$, which work. The hist of $w$ does all give positive values. Many thanks.